# Numeric array from string containing non-numeric characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a bunch of dates in some .xml files in this format : `2013-02-10 12:00` (year, month, day, hour, minutes) and I want to create a Date object from it.

I did `new Date(stringFromXml)` in Chrome and it works, but it doesn't work in Firefox/IE.

What I wanted to do is split that string in a 5 element array and create a `Date` object manually with the constructor that accepts a year, month, day, etc. The thing is that I couldn't make it work with regular expressions and `.split` isn't the most elegant solution.

I already know about [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) but I don't want to add another library to my project.

What should I do to make this work? Also, I am using jQuery

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format is always the same, you can hack it together like this:

```
var parts = '2013-02-10 12:00'.split(/[: -]/);
var d = new Date(
    parts[0] /* year */, parts[1] /* month */, parts[2] /* day */, 
    parts[3] /* hour */, parts[4] /* minute */
);
```

If you already have the [`Datepicker`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) widget, you can use the [`parseDate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) function from the date picker extension:

```
var date = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd hh:mm', '2013-02-10 12:00');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

```
var date = Date.parse(" date string here ");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on the right path...

`var dateParts = date.split(/(-| |:)/);`